# Custom Exception for missing fields in pydantic

Tags: python, exception, pydantic

I want to catch the exception that validators raise of a Pydantic as such. I currently got a working set up like so:

```
class MissingPhoneNumber(ValueError):
    pass

class SMS(Basemodel):
    
    id: str       
    phone_number: Optional[str] = None
    
    @validator('phone_number', always=True)
    def phone_number(cls, v):
        if not v:
            raise MissingPhoneNumber
        return v

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    try:
        event = SMS()
    except ValidationError as e:
            for e2 in e.errors():
                if e2['type'] == 'value_error.missingphonenumber':
                    print('caught Exception')
                
                raise e
```

However, it is quite messy and I'd rather catch it like so:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    try:
        event = SMS()
    except MissingPhoneNumber:
        print('caught Exception')
```

Is there a way in Pydantic to accomplish this? Running on Pydantic 1.10.9

Comment: in your example the SMS class is missing inheritance from BaseModel, which is required by pydantic for defining data models and performing validation.

Comment: @pyjedy The class it inherited from did have the BaseModel inheritance, I updated the question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example with custom Exception using pydantic validator

```
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class MissingPhoneNumber(Exception):
    pass


class SMS(BaseModel):
    phone_number: Optional[str] = None

    @validator('phone_number', always=True)
    def validate_phone_number(cls, v):
        if not v:
            raise MissingPhoneNumber("custom error message")
        return v


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        event = SMS()
    except MissingPhoneNumber as e:
        print(type(e).__name__, e)  # MissingPhoneNumber custom error message
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your answer is correct, but in my code I also made another mistake.

My custom Exception class inherited from ValueError instead of Exception, this caused the issue.

Comment: What Pydantic version are you using? Could you please add it to your answer?

Comment: @edd313 Running on pydantic 1.10.9